# Greatest common divisor of multiple (more than 2) numbers

Tags: matlab, math

I am seeking for the easiest solution to get the greatest common divisor of multiple values. Something like:

```
x=gcd_array(30,40,35) % Should return 5
x=gcd_array(30,40) % Should return 10
```

How would you solve this?

Many thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Euclidian greatest common divisor for more then two numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231733/euclidian-greatest-common-divisor-for-more-then-two-numbers)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
gcd(a,b,c) = gcd(a,gcd(b,c))
```

Which means you can use recursion.

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.73.3&rep=rep1&type=pdf&ei=90jgT9KPAtLS4QSNlOGdDQ&usg=AFQjCNGH_GewFofxWPfX2BDN6T5NF9PxAA

Answer (score 0):

```
 `% GCD OF list of Nos using Eucledian Alogorithm 
  function GCD= GCD(n);
  x=1;
  p=n;
  while(size(n,2))>=2
  p= n(:,size(n,2)-1:size(n,2));
  n=n(1,1:size(n,2)-2);
  x=1;
  while(x~=0)
  x= max(p)-min(p);
  p = [x,min(p)];
  end    
  n=[n,max(p)];
  p= [];
  end
  '
```

Comment: Care to explain your solution?

Comment: Function GCD takes list list of numbers as its argument
Now , using gcd(a1,a2,a3)= gcd(a1,gcd(a2,a3). 
Store the last two numbers in different matrix P 
To calculate the GCD of P , 
use the algorithm 
gcd of a1 & a2= a1-a2
       (a1-a2)-a2 and so on till u get 0 or 1
       store the GCD value again in n so that now you have n = (a1,a2,a3............a(n-2),gcd(an-1,an))