# GCD calucation for 4 Numbers

Tags: java

Edit BoxesI am developing an application which consists of Edit Texts, I will explain clearly based on steps:

a) Based on Spinner some item will contain 3 edit text boxes, and some will contain 4 edit-text boxes.

b) for this i will to calculate **GCD**, Currently i am using using **GCD calculation** for two Edit boxes, how can i calculate for  ** **Three Edit Boxes and Four Edit Boxes****

```
private long gcd(long a, long b) {

        if (b == 0)
            return a;
        else
            return gcd(b, a % b);
    }
```

How i can write code for Three and four Edit Boxes.

Comment: By "Edit Boxes." DYM values?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Euclidian greatest common divisor for more then two numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231733/euclidian-greatest-common-divisor-for-more-then-two-numbers) or [Greatest common divisor of multiple (more than 2) numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098274/greatest-common-divisor-of-multiple-more-than-2-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are finding the gcd of four numbers (a,b,c,d) then split should work.

Try this way:

```
gcd(a,b,c,d) = gcd(gcd (a,b) , gcd(c,d))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the two-argument `gcd` function:

```
gcd(a, b, c, d) = gcd(gcd(gcd(a, b), c), d)
```

This works for basically any number of arguments using a recursive implementation.

Answer (score 1):

[The gcd of three numbers can be computed as gcd(a, b, c) = gcd(gcd(a, b), c), or in some different way by applying commutativity and associativity. This can be extended to any number of numbers.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Properties)