# matlab gives wrong result for modulo function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create function responsible for finding divisor of 90 figure smaller than given tempMaxAngle. For example my function should return 6 for tempMaxAngle=7 or 30 for tempMaxAngle=31 or 22.5 for tempMaxAngle=23, etc. Unfortunately it is not working correctly - I am getting strange values. Here is my algorythm:

```
function maxAngle = angletest(tempMaxAngle)
    format long g;
    tempMaxAngle = tempMaxAngle*10;
    tempMaxAngle = floor(tempMaxAngle)/10;
    while mod(90,tempMaxAngle)>0
        modResult =mod(90,tempMaxAngle)
        tempMaxAngle = tempMaxAngle - 0.1
    end
    maxAngle=tempMaxAngle;
end
```

partial result for tempMaxAngle=7 (while section result):

```
tempMaxAngle =

                   6.9


modResult =

     0.299999999999995


tempMaxAngle =

                   6.8


 modResult =

      1.59999999999999


tempMaxAngle =

                   6.7


modResult =

      2.89999999999998


tempMaxAngle =

                   6.6


modResult =

      4.19999999999998


tempMaxAngle =

                   6.5


modResult =

      5.49999999999998


tempMaxAngle =

                   6.4


modResult =

     0.399999999999966


tempMaxAngle =

                   6.3


modResult =

      1.79999999999996


tempMaxAngle =

                   6.2


modResult =

      3.19999999999997


tempMaxAngle =

                   6.1


modResult =

      4.59999999999996


tempMaxAngle =

                     6


modResult =

      5.99999999999995


tempMaxAngle =

                   5.9


modResult =

      1.49999999999994


tempMaxAngle =

                   5.8


modResult =

      2.99999999999993


tempMaxAngle =

                   5.7


modResult =

      4.49999999999993


tempMaxAngle =

      5.60000000000001


modResult =

     0.399999999999929
```

Why it keeps returing that kind of values instead of simple 6.9, 6.8, 6.7, etc. and similar for modulo function? How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you not doing `mod(90,7)` directly?

Comment: Because it's a function that I would like to use for other values, not only 7.

Comment: Now I get the question, it should read: find `x ≤ tempAngle` that divides 90 evenly.

Comment: Don't understand what you are doing, but based on the textual description: have a look at finding the GCD http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11098274/greatest-common-divisor-of-multiple-more-than-2-numbers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is due to small errors in the internal floating representation.

Have a look at [matlab double comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8959452/matlab-double-comparison)

Comment: Thank you very much, sd_round function is what I needed.